# Is the default Windows 8 UEFI/GPT Partition Scheme necessary?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, uefi

I'm installing Windows 8 on a UEFI computer with a GPT drive array (RAID 0), and whenever I try to create a new partition the installer creates additional partions according to the [default Windows 8 partition scheme](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825702.aspx#ChooseDefault). Is the presence of these partitions mandatory? And if they are not, how can I avoid their creation?